# Combine Document and AggregationOperation Stages in a Spring MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline?

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Spring Data MongoDB has helpful builder classes for aggregation stages, like `Aggregation.match()` or `Aggregation.sort()`. Objects returned by those methods implement the `AggregationOperation` interface, which allows them to be used `Aggregation.newAggregation()` to create a new pipeline, which is in turn passed to `mongoTemplate.aggregate()`.

The problem is not all Mongo aggregation stages have builder methods, e.g. [`$lookup` with a correlated subquery](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection). It appears in those cases I have to manually create a `Document` with JSON describing the stage. But I can't find a way to use an `AggregationOperation` and a `Document` based stage together. Is there a way to wrap a `Document` into an `AggregationOperation`, or similar?

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue / feature that remains open to this day [spring-data-mongodb - #3322](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3322)

**Workaround:** Implement `AggregationOperation` interface

#### Java 1.7

```
AggregationOperation lookup = new AggregationOperation() {

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document(...); // put here $lookup stage
    }

};
```

#### >= Java 1.8

```
AggregationOperation lookup = ctx -> new Document(...); // put here $lookup stage
```

Comment: Hi Valijon, looks like toDocument method of AggregationOperation has been deprecated in favor of toPipelineStages method. However, when I include AggregationOperation in my stages, it still enters toDocument method. Do you have any experience with using new method in aggregations?